# Typescript Object is possibly 'null'.ts(2531) when using querySelectorAll

Tags: typescript

```
class Test {
  state = {
    elements: {
      container: null
    }
  };

  constructor(container: HTMLElement | null, options: {}) {
    //permet de prendre les options du user ainsi que de set des variables
    if (!container) {
      throw new Error("No container element was provided");
      return;
    }

    if (typeof container === "string") {
      const containerElement: any = document.querySelector(container);

      this.state.elements.container = containerElement;
    }
  }

  init() {
    if (this.state.elements.container != null) {
      this.state.elements.container.querySelectorAll(".box")[0];
    }
  }
}

export default Test;
```

I keep getting an error on this line : `this.state.elements.container.querySelectorAll(".box")[0];`

I cannot figure out what I need to do so it doesn't output that error and other dev have asked this question, but the only fix I found is to wrap it in != null and that doesn't work.

Any help is appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we set an object's property to `null` without giving the object a type, and if we have enabled `strictNullChecks`, the compiler will assume that the property's type *is* null. Here is an [example of that in the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=let%20case1%20%3D%20null%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Type%20'%22nope1%22'%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20type%20'null'.%0D%0Acase1%20%3D%20'nope1'%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20case2%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20prop%3A%20null%2C%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Type%20'%22nope2%22'%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20type%20'null'.%0D%0Acase2.prop%20%3D%20'nope2'%3B).

```
let case1 = null;

// Type '"nope1"' is not assignable to type 'null'.
case1 = 'nope1';

let case2 = {
    prop: null,
}

// Type '"nope2"' is not assignable to type 'null'.
case2.prop = 'nope2';
```

Without using all the React boilerplate, you could declare your component's state type [like this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20TestState%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20elements%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20container%3A%20HTMLElement%20%7C%20null%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20default%20class%20Test%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20state%3A%20Readonly%3CTestState%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20elements%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20container%3A%20null%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(container%3A%20HTMLElement%20%7C%20null%2C%20options%3A%20%7B%7D)%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(!container)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20throw%20new%20Error(%22No%20container%20element%20was%20provided%22)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(typeof%20container%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22string%22)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20containerElement%3A%20any%20%3D%20document.querySelector(container)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.state.elements.container%20%3D%20containerElement%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20init()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(this.state.elements.container)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.state.elements.container.querySelectorAll(%22.box%22)%5B0%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D).

```
type TestState = {
    elements: {
        container: HTMLElement | null
    }
}

export default class Test {

    state: Readonly<TestState> = {
        elements: {
            container: null
        }
    };

    constructor(container: HTMLElement | null, options: {}) {

        if (!container) {
            throw new Error("No container element was provided");
        }

        if (typeof container === "string") {
            const containerElement: any = document.querySelector(container);
            this.state.elements.container = containerElement;
        }
    }

    init() {
        if (this.state.elements.container) {
            this.state.elements.container.querySelectorAll(".box")[0];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Fair enough, but how can I fix this so Typescript doesn't output an error. Is there a better way of coding this? Is the structure ok?

Comment: @Stephen I added a way that you can get around that.

Comment: I don't want to be difficult, but is it possible not to add all the react stuff, I'm doing a pure Typscript Project. How can I add TestState to my test class?

Comment: @Stephen Thank you for appreciating the extra work... I updated the answer to avoid the React boilerplate.